# Вставка изображения в jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, не так много работал с сервлетами, результат соответствующий. Проблема вывести изображения через jsp или html реализуя war-файл. Использую glassfish и maven. Вчера получил ответы, если папка с изображениями не находится внутри WEB-INF, то получить доступ к изображению можно напрямую из jsp
        img src="images/russian_life.jpg"/
И второй ответ Если же папка с изображениями лежит внутри WEB-INF или изображение находится в БД, то получить к нему доступ можно только через сервлет. Тогда ты загружаешь изображение в сервлет, который просто в OutputStream пишет все изображение и ставит правильный Content-Type. На jsp странице используешь тег img src=«/path/to/serlvet»/>

В первом случае куда бы я не положил изображение, в ресурсы, в webapp изображение напрямую не вставляется. Во втором случае: с помощью какого метода нужно загрузить изображение в сервлет. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

на винде ищет картинку в C:\path\loadFiles.На линуксе думаю во временной директории.

```
    httpPost(request,response){
            InputStream in = null;
            String rootPath = "path\\";
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "loadFiles");
            File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyImage.jpg");
            in = new FileInputStream(f);
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

Comment: кстати нужно добавить библиотеку apache-commons-io.